# Sorting MongoCollection group function in PHP

Tags: php, mongodb

I need to do a complex query on a mongoDB database using the MongoCollection-Group function and then i need to sort the results

They say mongoCursor has a built in sort() function. (http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries)

But in the PHP library,I see that only the find() function returns a Cursor. group() function returns an array. (http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mongocollection.php)

Will i have to do it manually ? Its a bit tedious because it has nested documents.

Comment: Is there any code involved? As things stand my best guess is that your problem is that you haven't supported unicorns.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to do this manually in your application code. The result of the group() function is one document, with in its `results` field an array of documents that form the result. You will have to sort that array yourself.